# WordPress PHP Form Won't Send

Tags: php, forms, wordpress, email

I'm probably missing something really simple here or have a little typo in my code but the PHP form I've created for a WordPress site I'm building won't send. If there are errors in the form, the validation works (except for if you just enter a name) but when you fill in the form correctly and click submit, it simply goes to the page it's meant to for processing and says 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'. Plus the mail doesn't get sent.

**EDIT**

The link to the dev site is http://dev.garethdaine.com/inkframe/.

The page for processing does exist. Here's my code:

**Form Code**

```
<form name="quick-contact" class="quick-contact" method="post" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/get-in-touch/">
    <h3>Request a Call Back</h3>
    <h4><label for="name">Name</label></h4>
    <input id="name" name="name" type="text" />
    <h4><label for="email">Email</label></h4>
    <input id="email" name="email" type="text" />
    <h4><label for="phone">Phone</label></h4>
    <input id="phone" name="phone" type="text" />
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
    <input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="true" />
    <input type="hidden" name="required" id="required" class="required" />
</form>
```

**PHP Code**

```
    <?php
    /*
    * Template Name: Contact
    */
    if( isset( $_POST['submitted'] ) ) {
        $to = get_option( 'admin_email' );

        if( trim( $_POST['name'] ) === '' ) {
            $nameError = 'You did not enter your name.';
            $hasError = true;
        } else {
            $name = trim( $_POST['name'] );
        }

        if( trim( $_POST['email'] ) === '' ) {
            $emailError = 'You did not enter your email address.';
            $hasError = true;
        } else if( !preg_match( "/^[[:alnum:]][a-z0-9_.-]*@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/i", trim( $_POST['email'] ) ) ) {
            $emailError = 'You entered an invalid email address.';
            $hasError = true;
        } else {
            $email = trim( $_POST['email'] );
        }

        if( trim( $_POST['phone'] ) === '' ) {
            $phoneError = 'You did not enter your telephone number.';
            $hasError = true;
        } else if( !is_numeric( $_POST['phone'] ) ) {
            $phoneError = 'You have entered an invalid phone number.';
            $hasError = true;
        } else {
            $phone = trim( $_POST['phone'] );
        }

        if( !empty( $_POST['required'] ) ) {
            $requiredError = 'You appear to be a robot. If you are human, please try again.';
            $hasError = true;
        }

        if( !isset( $hasError ) ) {
            $subject = 'Call Back Request from ' . $name;
            $body = "Name: $name \n\nEmail: $email \n\nPhone: $phone";
            $headers = 'From: ' . $name . ' <' . $emailTo . '>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email;

            wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers );
            $emailSent = true;
        }   
    }
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="content" role="main">
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>   
            <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
            <div class="entry-content">
                <?php if( isset( $emailSent ) && $emailSent == true ) { ?>
                    <p><strong>Your message has been sent successfully. Someone will be in touch shortly. Thanks.</strong></p>
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                <?php } else { ?>
                    <?php if( isset( $hasError ) ) { ?>
                        <p class="error">Sorry, an error has occured.<p>
                        <ul>
                            <?php if( $nameError != '' ) { ?>
                                <li>
                                    <span class="error"><?php echo $nameError; ?></span>

                                </li>
                            <?php } ?>
                            <?php if( $emailError != '' ) { ?>
                                <li>
                                    <span class="error"><?php echo $emailError; ?></span>
                                </li>
                            <?php } ?>
                            <?php if( $phoneError != '' ) { ?>
                                <li>
                                    <span class="error"><?php echo $phoneError; ?></span>
                                </li>
                            <?php } ?>
                            <?php if( !empty( $requiredError ) ) { ?>
                                <li>
                                    <span class="error"><?php echo $requiredError; ?></span>
                                </li>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </ul>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Dumb question: Is your get-in-touch Page using the defined Contact template?

Comment: Yes, it is using the correct contact.php template.

Comment: I notice when you navigate directly to the Get In Touch Page (without form submission) the Page Content renders without issue. However, when the form IS submitted, no content can be found. What happens if you comment out everything between the `if( isset( $_POST['submitted'] ) )` block? Does the content render upon form submission? If you place an echo statement in that block, does the echo statement fire?

Comment: Try adding the content type and encoding to the headers to see if that works -    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n';

Comment: @maiorano84 Thanks. No the echo statement doesn't output anything.

Comment: @McNab I also tried adding the content type and encoding to the $headers variable but no joy.

Comment: OK, I moved the PHP code to below the header with th echo statement 'Test' in it and it shows, as long as the form is empty, as soon as the form has anything in it it shows no content? Weird or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK Guys,

Looks like I've finally figured out the problem. All the code, in all it's variations was fine and works, except for one tiny thing. The variable '$name' is used by the WordPress system to display the blog name, and as I was using that as my variable for the name field on my form it was causing issues. Who knew.

Anyway, I simply changed it to use '$fullName' and changed the id and name attributes on the form to 'full-name' and everything worked great.

Thanks to @maiorano84 for pointing me in the right direction to debug the problem.

Anyway, below is my amended code, so others can make use of it.

**Form Code**

```
<form name="quick-contact" class="quick-contact" method="post" action="<?php bloginfo( 'url' ); ?>/get-in-touch/">
    <h3>Request a Call Back</h3>
    <h4><label for="full-name">Full Name</label></h4>
    <input id="full-name" name="full-name" type="text" />
    <h4><label for="email">Email</label></h4>
    <input id="email" name="email" type="text" />
    <h4><label for="phone">Phone</label></h4>
    <input id="phone" name="phone" type="text" />
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
    <input type="hidden" name="required" id="required" class="required" />
</form>
```

**PHP Code**

```
<?php
    /*
    * Template Name: Contact
    */
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST" ) {
        $to = get_option( 'admin_email' );

        if( trim( $_POST['full-name'] ) === '' ) {
            $nameError = 'You did not enter your name.';
            $hasError = true;
        } else {
            $fullName = trim( $_POST['full-name'] );
        }

        if( trim( $_POST['email'] ) === '' ) {
            $emailError = 'You did not enter your email address.';
            $hasError = true;
        } else if( !preg_match( "/^[[:alnum:]][a-z0-9_.-]*@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/i", trim( $_POST['email'] ) ) ) {
            $emailError = 'You entered an invalid email address.';
            $hasError = true;
        } else {
            $email = trim( $_POST['email'] );
        }

        if( trim( $_POST['phone'] ) === '' ) {
            $phoneError = 'You did not enter your telephone number.';
            $hasError = true;
        } else if( !is_numeric( $_POST['phone'] ) ) {
            $phoneError = 'You have entered an invalid phone number.';
            $hasError = true;
        } else {
            $phone = trim( $_POST['phone'] );
        }

        if( !empty( $_POST['required'] ) ) {
            $requiredError = 'You appear to be a robot. If you are human, please try again.';
            $hasError = true;
        }

        if( !isset( $hasError ) ) {
            if ( !isset( $to ) || ( $to == '' ) ) {
                $to = get_option( 'admin_email' );
            }
            $subject = 'Call Back Request from ' . $fullName;
            $body = "Name: $fullName <br />Email: $email <br />Phone: $phone";
            $headers[] = 'From: ' . $fullName . ' <' . $email . '>';
            $headers[] = 'Reply-To: ' . $email;
            $headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8';

            wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers );
            $emailSent = true;
        }
    }
?>
<div class="content" role="main">
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>   
            <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
            <div class="entry-content">
                <?php if( isset( $emailSent ) && $emailSent == true ) { ?>
                    <p><strong>Your message has been sent successfully. Someone will be in touch shortly. Thanks.</strong></p>
                <?php } else { ?>
                    <?php var_dump($headers); ?>
                    <?php if( isset( $hasError ) ) { ?>
                        <p class="error">Sorry, an error has occured.<p>
                        <ul>
                            <?php if( $nameError != '' ) { ?>
                                <li>
                                    <span class="error"><?php echo $nameError; ?></span>

                                </li>
                            <?php } ?>
                            <?php if( $emailError != '' ) { ?>
                                <li>
                                    <span class="error"><?php echo $emailError; ?></span>
                                </li>
                            <?php } ?>
                            <?php if( $phoneError != '' ) { ?>
                                <li>
                                    <span class="error"><?php echo $phoneError; ?></span>
                                </li>
                            <?php } ?>
                            <?php if( !empty( $requiredError ) ) { ?>
                                <li>
                                    <span class="error"><?php echo $requiredError; ?></span>
                                </li>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </ul>
                    <?php } ?>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php the_content(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Ouch!  Hard one, well done for getting to the bottom of it and thanks for posting the solution.  Remember to mark your own answer as correct so it shows it's been solved.

Answer (score 0):

Tell me if is arrived an email, if not change
$to = get_option( 'admin_email' ); 
with
$to = your@email.com; //exemple

When you have changed try and tell me if it works ;)

Comment: That won't affect anything, as I've tested the $to variable and it contains the admin email as a string, so it is set and working.

Comment: Also, an email did not arrive. As I say, the form is not working.

Comment: I' ve just tried the code and so works, instead of this:
if ( !isset( $to ) || ( $to == '' ) ) {
                $to = get_option( 'admin_email' );
            }

Use only: $to = 'youremail'; //don' t use that if

Comment: The code still doesn't work, even with that change. I've amended my question above to show the full contact.php code.

Comment: Have you tried to put the full code in an unique file?, I tried so and it worked

Comment: Yeah, the problem was with the $name variable, as it's used by WordPress to display the blog name.

Comment: Well ;). I hadn't problem, was strange.